# Add another relationship in role model spatie

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-permission

I've another relation that attach to role but when I tried to call it in controller with with/load/relations model it doesn't work. I can't call any relationship in role model except permissions.

```
class Role extends \Spatie\Permission\Models\Role
{
    public static $rules = [
        'name'=>'required'
    ];
    //protected $relations = ['satkers'];
    //protected $with = ['satkers'];

    //RELATIONS
    public function satkers(){
        return $this->belongsTo(MasterSatker::class, 'master_pelaksana_satker_id', 'id')->withDefault(['name'=>'']);
    }
}
```

How call it in controller?
I've tried show it like this `$role->load('satkers')` and `$role->satkers`, it doesn't work. I got an error `Call to undefined relationship [satkers] on model [Spatie\Permission\Models\Role]` and null. I tried dd the $role, here is it what i got

```
Spatie\Permission\Models\Role {#1587 ▼
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "roles"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:6 [▶]
  #original: array:6 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼ //it just show permissions
    "permissions" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1975 ▶}
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  -permissionClass: null
}
```

Comment: I would call the Class differently because "Role" Class already exists.

Comment: And you get an instance of the Spatie Class it seems, not yours. Check what you are calling

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot, i've change it in config and change the imported role in controller and it works!

Comment: @RayCoder ... I am facing the same issue ... can you share your code ?

Comment: @FaISalBLiNK Make sure you dont call (import) Role from spatie but from the model you created (`use App\Model\Role`), if you call from spatie and from your model make sure it has different name

Comment: @RayCoder thanks ... I am trying to return the relation for the User model ... in the User model I only imported `use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;`

Comment: @FaISalBLiNK Can you explain the details of your problem? Maybe i can help

Comment: @RayCoder ... I created a many-to-many relation between `ItPolicy` and `Role` models but when I try to retrieve `User::where('email', $request->email)
            ->with(['profile', 'positionSummary', 'contractSummary', 'roles.itPolicies', 'practices'])
            ->firstOrFail();` I get this error message `Call to undefined relationship [itPolicies] on model [Spatie\\Permission\\Models\\Role].`

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/discussions/2137 @FaISalBLiNK

Comment: @RayCoder thanks ... I have gone through the documentation for the Spatie laravel-permissions package and figured out how to extend the Spatie's Role class